# How to review index created with lucene.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, lucene, lucene.net

I'm in process of using **lucene.net** to implement *auto-suggest* and *faceted search* for a website.

Trying my hands with Analysis/Indexing,
After index is created,

1. Is there any way to retrieve and view paged listing of indexed documents.
2. Is there a way to retrieve tokens/terms and offset/positions stored for each field in index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Luke** tool, which can open a Lucene index and let you peek at the contents. It's very instructive.

I'm not including a link to the tool here, because it's poorly maintained. You have to download a Luke version matching your Lucene version - and several people released the tool for specific Lucene versions, find the one that's right for you.

(Lucene.NET indexes are compatible with Lucene indexes, and version numbers do match)

Comment: can you help me with another question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037593/auto-suggest-using-lucene-net

Comment: Nope, sorry, I've never used the facets feature so I don't know much about this subject.